# Using Docker in interactive mode using an official Microsoft .Net Core SDK image

Tags: docker, .net-core

I'm trying to enter interactive mode using an official Microsoft .Net Core image and use typical .Net commands such as 'dotnet build', but all I get is an '>' cursor. What am I doing wrong?

I'm using the following command:

```
docker run -it -v $(pwd):/app' -w '/app' -p 8000:80 mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk /bin/bash
```

I was hoping to get a root command prompt, but all I'm getting is '>'

Comment: try to add dot after your command

Comment: I'm not sure where or how a dot would here?

Comment: Try this command `docker run -it -v $(pwd):/app' -w '/app' -p 8000:80 mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk /bin/bash .` dot mean workdir

Comment: But I've already specified the workdir with: ```-w '/app'```

Answer (score 1):

```
Usage:  docker exec [OPTIONS] CONTAINER COMMAND [ARG...]

Run a command in a running container

Options:
  -d, --detach               Detached mode: run command in the background
      --detach-keys string   Override the key sequence for detaching a
                             container
  -e, --env list             Set environment variables
  -i, --interactive          Keep STDIN open even if not attached
      --privileged           Give extended privileges to the command
  -t, --tty                  Allocate a pseudo-TTY
  -u, --user string          Username or UID (format:
                             <name|uid>[:<group|gid>])
  -w, --workdir string       Working directory inside the container
```

After running your container, run command `docker ps` to take `[Container ID]`

And after you are able to run the command like there `docker exec -it [Container ID] bash .`

Comment: I don't want to create and then run a container though.

Answer (score 0):

You are misssing the initial quote here:

```
-v $(pwd):/app'
```

That should be:

```
-v "$(pwd):/app"
```

It needs to be a double-quote for $(pwd) to be evaluated correctly by the shell. Otherwise the shell will send the literal `$(pwd)` which is not a valid path.

Answer (score 0):

It seems no one gives a direct answer, this one works for me:

```
docker run --rm -it -v $PWD:/app -w /app -p 8000:80 mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk /bin/bash
```

Answer (score 0):

The image path above is not what Microsoft refers to in their docs. Not sure if has changed since above, but no 'core' in the path:

mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0
(from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/net-core-net-framework-containers/official-net-docker-images)

This then works for me:

```
docker run --rm -it -v "$PWD:/app" -w /app -p 8000:80 mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 /bin/bash
```